# Unexplainable error using GEMM or any matrix multiplication in OpenCV 3

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, matrix-multiplication, opencv3.0

I am using OpenCV 3.0.0 C++ on Eclipse 3.8, Linux Mint 17.2 (64bit)

I am trying a simple multiplication using the [GEMM](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#gemm) function, but it doesn't work. And neither does any other matrix multiplication method. When I run the program, it just hangs until I press terminate, at which point an error pops up saying "Terminate Failed" even though it does terminate it. No other build errors, no output to console. Nothing. My eclipse does not crash (I can execute other programs afterwards just fine).
Gemm just dose not work.

I have tried other versions of eclipse, making new projects, new workspaces, reinstalling opencv and waiting for the "hang" to "complete". I am using the correct libraries (Debug versions) and a basic "OpenCV display image" program works.

I have not tried a different version of OpenCV, and would prefer not to.

Here is my test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

 int main( void )
 {
  float a[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
  float b[] = {5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0};
  float c[] = {9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0};

  cv::Mat A = cv::Mat(2,2,CV_32FC1,a).clone();
  cv::Mat B = cv::Mat(2,2,CV_32FC1, b).clone();
  cv::Mat C = cv::Mat(2,2,CV_32FC1, c).clone();
  cv::Mat D; // result

  // D = A*B
  cv::gemm(A, B, 1.0, cv::Mat(), 0.0, D);

  std::cout << D << std::endl;

  waitKey(0);
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I just tried this code on my setup (Windows + OpenCV 2.4.11 + VS2013) and everything works fine. You said you're using `Debug versions`... what happens when you debug (what's in `D`)? By the way, you just need `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`...

Comment: I had other code that I removed hence the extra includes. During debug it's the same story. It opens a thread, and then stops and hangs. It stops somewhere in a malloc call, but I can't be sure because it takes forever to go through each and every process tick.

Comment: works for me too. You probably messed up something in the configuration. Do you use 64bit version, with the correct compiler? Also, when you make it work, you can simply use `D = A*B;`